# PHP mail() function $to not working properly

Tags: php, sendmail

my HTML code:

```html
<form role="form" method="post" >
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email" name="email" type="text" autofocus>
        </div>

        <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
        <input type="submit" href="dashboard.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block btn-warning" value="Reset" name="sub">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

my PHP mail() code:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$to = $email;
$subject = "Password Recovery";
$full="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$reffurl=str_replace("forget_pass_nw_pass.php","",$full);

$message = "You are receiving this e-mail because you have requested to recover your password.";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <noreply@caveo.sg>' . "\r\n";

$mail_sent = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

i tried changing

> $to = $email

to

> $to = "xxx@gmail.com"

and it actually works. but when it's $to to $email, no email is being sent.

Comment: It simple means that $_POST['email'] is either null value or this index is not made. Can you show your form code because its not in your mentioned code.

Comment: Are you getting `$_POST['email']` value within your PHP file

Comment: i have tried echo "$email"; and it actually returns the email user types into the form and not a null or wrong string.

Comment: Please check email configuration on your server

Comment: On submit you are sending to another page?

Comment: Christian: my website is hosted on AWS EC2 and email is with Bluehost. Settings should be correct because i have managed to send and receive emails successfully.

Comment: You should use `var_dump()` to debug variables, not `echo()`. Also, what is `<input href="dashboard.php"`? There's no such attribute as `href` in `<input>`. Maybe you meant to set it as the `action` attribute of your `<form>`.

Comment: If every thing correct then try to trim your $email at the time of assigning it to $to. that is only the possible error in your case as you said that everything is fine

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a extra spacing problem.
change

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

to

```
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
// Sanitize E-mail Address
$email =filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
// Validate E-mail Address
$email= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!$email){
echo "Invalid Sender's Email";
}
else{
    $to =  $_POST['email'];   
    $to = $email;
$subject = "Password Recovery";
$full="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$reffurl=str_replace("forget_pass_nw_pass.php","",$full);

$message = "You are receiving this e-mail because you have requested to recover your password.";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <noreply@caveo.sg>' . "\r\n";

$mail_sent = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: @Iftikhar the concern is that it is used to check if is email is declared or not